# Selenium python automation could not gracefully save and close the application

Tags: python, excel, selenium, automation

To automate excel sheets and save changes, I'm using Selenium Python. I was unable to click on  save and close the excel spreadsheet, but not terminate(kill) it. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Without much more details of what exactly is your actual code we will not be able to help here

Comment: The code is somewhat lengthy, however the essential idea is as follows: I used Selenium to open an excel file online and change the contents of the spreadsheet. Now comes the problem: I need to save and close Excel in order for it to update itself. With selenium, however, I am unable to hit the save button in Excel.